# Where's my silver air-travel?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, badges

412 air-travel × 81 and no silver tag badge :(

Here https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=silver

> Earn at least 400 total score for at least 80 non-community wiki answers in the air-travel tag

Comment: Yeah, I broken into your account and stole it. Silver is pretty valuable, you know. I've already sold it on the black market in India.

Answer (score 5):

Community wiki answers don't count towards tag badges since they are group effort. Who would you award the tag to? Everyone on the site? Whomever edited the CW? Me because I deserve it more than pnuts?

Also there's caching involved here as always on SE. If my memory serves me right, tag badges are updated once at the beginning of each UTC day.

Comment: I presumed the profile page displays badge progression.

Answer (score 3):

You currently [only have 76 answers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A4188+[air-travel]+is%3Aanswer) in that tag. The other six posts seem to be questions.

I also have no idea whether CW answers are added in that list or not, but if they are, you need to deduct them, too.

Comment: @pnuts Probably just Fiskdal’s doing after he broke into OP’s account ;)